# How to deploy strapi with MySQL db?

Tags: node.js, strapi

Trying to deploy strapi on a production server in a docker container. Image builds, compose works, but when my container starts with the command:

`NODE_ENV=production npm run start &`

I get the error:

> [2019-11-04T18:26:48.779Z] error Impossible to register the 'category'
>   model. [2019-11-04T18:26:48.780Z] error TypeError: Unknown SSL profile
>   'false'

I have created MySQL database on a production server, credentials are correct. What's wrong? Deploying it is so frustrating experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue come from the `ssl` attribute of you `./config/environme nts/production/database.json` file.

Try to set it manually to false.

```
{
  ...
  "settings": {
    ...
    "ssl": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i solved this already, by clearing `options` object in database.json and mentioned by you `ssl`, why it is in 17.4 beta by default? It causes issues on deployment.